# jQuery Validation -> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.each')

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery validation to validate a form. The form looks like the following:

```
    <div id="app_install_off" class="edit-ph mtop20"><h3 class="stakes-form-title-saved">APP INSTALL <span class="blue-txt"><!--(saved)--></span></h3><a href="#"><img border="0" align="right" style="margin:0 15px 0 0" src="../img/edit-button.png"></a></div>
<div id="app_install_on" class="appinstall-ph">
<form novalidate="novalidate" action="/sweepstakes/campaignstep2" id="AppInstallTaskCampaignstep2Form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input name="_method" value="POST" type="hidden"></div>            <div class="form-header"><h3 class="stakes-form-title">APP INSTALL <span class="greentext">(not saved)</span></h3></div>
        <div class="form-content-area">
            <div class="app-field-ph">
                <ul class="apps-form">
                    <li class="f-label">App Name</li>
                    <li class="input-ph"><div class="input text"><input name="data[AppInstallTask][task_title]" class="appsform-field" id="AppInstallTaskTaskTitle" border="0" type="text"></div></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="apps-form whitebg">
                    <li class="f-label">Package Name</li>
                    <li class="input-ph"><div class="input text"><input name="data[AppInstallTask][app_package_name]" class="appsform-field" value="Example: Com.MyAppPackage" id="AppInstallTaskAppPackageName" border="0" type="text"></div></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="apps-form">
                    <li class="f-label">Market URL</li>
                    <li class="input-ph"><div class="input text"><input name="data[AppInstallTask][web_url]" class="appsform-field" id="AppInstallTaskWebUrl" border="0" type="text"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="save-clear-ph">
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/clear-button.png" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="Javascript:void(0)"><img id="app_install_submit" src="../img/save-button.png" border="0"></a>
                <input name="data[AppInstallTask][task_type]" value="Download an App" id="AppInstallTaskTaskType" type="hidden">                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<!-- The next similar block -->
<div id="like_fb_on" class="appinstall-ph mtop20">
    <form action="/sweepstakes/campaignstep2" id="LikeFbTaskCampaignstep2Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>            <div class="form-header"><h3 class="stakes-form-title">LIKE FACEBOOK PAGE <span class="greentext">(not saved)</span></h3></div>
        <div class="form-content-area">
            <div class="app-field-ph">
                <ul class="apps-form">
                    <li class="f-label">Campaign Option Name</li>
                    <li class="input-ph"><div class="input text"><input name="data[LikeFbTask][task_title]" class="appsform-field" border="0" type="text" id="LikeFbTaskTaskTitle"/></div></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="apps-form whitebg">
                    <li class="f-label">Facebook Page URL</li>
                    <li class="input-ph"><div class="input text"><input name="data[LikeFbTask][web_url]" class="appsform-field" border="0" type="text" id="LikeFbTaskWebUrl"/></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="save-clear-ph">
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/clear-button.png" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="../img/save-button.png" border="0"></a>
                <input type="hidden" name="data[LikeFbTask][task_type]" value="Like Facebook Page" id="LikeFbTaskTaskType"/>                </div>
        </div>
    </form>    
</div>
```

On the click of the image (id = "app_install_submit"), I'm submitting the form. jQuery validation is implemented as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#AppInstallTaskCampaignstep2Form').validate({
        rules: {
            "data[AppInstallTask][task_title]": {
                required: true
            },
            customMessage: "required",
        }
    });
});
```

The click event is as following:

```
$('#app_install_submit').click(function(){
        $('#AppInstallTaskCampaignstep2Form').submit();
    });
```

Which is wrapped inside ready() as well.

This works for the first time, highlights the field with error class and message is appended in label. Any further clicks produce this 'nightmare' error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.each')

Also, while the form actually gets validated properly, it refuses to submit.

jQuery version: **v1.10.1**

Validate plugin version: **1.9.0**

Notes: There are other forms in this page, they have separate id, field names are not conflicting either. Also I've checked properly, there are no overlaps of forms. To add on to more frustration, this same set of files works in other pages of my site.

Looking forward to a pointer, where I might be going wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If that error was caused by `validate()` then the plugin would have a serious bug. Maybe the error is somewhere else in your event handler. Can you post more code?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've added html code to explain how more similar forms co-exists in the page with the form in question. Also added more jQuery codes to explain how I'm tracking the click event. This is really weird as the same plugin is working perfectly on other pages. I'm new to StackOverflow, so don't know if it's alright to paste the entire code of the page in here, else I would have done that. Let me know, and thanks again.

Comment: Which plugin is it anyway? I was only assuming it's [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/validation/). If it is, have you tried the current version?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the turn around time. I updated all the dependent files to most updated versions. But it seems the problem was within some of the other blocks I described above. Once I started removing them and putting them back one at a time, it worked perfectly.